# How to run Google assistant next time when once it is installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have installed Google assistant on my Ubuntu 16.04 lts. Once I installed it successfully on my PC what should be the command line to start the Google assistant or every time I have to reinstall it?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Once you set it up, you're all set. You can run the same commands each time, as you probably are already doing:

`googlesamples-assistant-hotword --device_model_id 'my-model-identifier'`